# Eslint: remove keyword function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I was wondering if there is a rule or a way to flag function declarations as an error in favor of arrow functions. As an example:

```
// error
 function foo() {
   return "bar"
 }

//acceptable
 const foo = () => "bar"
```

its pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find any rules or packages.

Comment: Well, you can enforce using function expressions only (check [func-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style) rule), but you can just allow usage of fat arrow funcs, not enforce it.

Comment: This has been discussed: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3140  https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3113  Might want to join the discussion there.

Comment: Remember though fat arrow `() => ` is not a replacement for `function() {}`. Later still have some usage especially you want to deal with `this` bindings in it

Comment: There are, of course, times you **need** to use a traditional function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`prefer-arrow-callback`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) rule, but it applies only to callbacks. If you want to disallow regular functions entirely, you can use the [`eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow) npm package.

Remember though that sometimes you might need a regular function, for example as a callback to `addEventListener`.